# SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'forEach'

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, internet-explorer-8

IE8 support property or method 'forEach'

```
$('.tabs').tabs();
$('#search-consumables [data-ajax-call]').change(function() {

    var $this = $(this),
        settings = $this.data(),
        $target = $(settings.target);

    $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: 'index.php?route=module/quicklookup/' + settings.ajaxCall,
       data: $this.closest('form').serializeArray(),
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(data) {
           var html = '';
           $target.find(':not(.blank)').remove();
           html = $target.html();
           data.forEach(function(entry) {
               html += '<option value="'+entry.id+'">'+entry.name+'</option>';
           });
           $target.html(html);
        }
    });
});
```

I have tried

```
$.each(data, function(entry) {
```

yet data then returns undefined, What am I missing to get this working in IE8?

Comment: `data` is of the type `object` which has no method `forEach()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first argument passed to the `jQuery.each` callback is the index of the value in the array; the second argument is the actual value.

Try using:

```
$.each(data, function(i, entry) {
    // your code here
});
```